# Dual booting windows/ubuntu not showing windows

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I had Windows 7 installed on my PC and tried to install Ubuntu 14.04. When I restart my computer, grub only shows Ubuntu, so I think I may have accidentally deleted Windows in the process.

I ran boot-repair and this is the output:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/11359162/

Is Windows 7 completely gone? If so, do I need to install Windows again from a CD? I did create a backup image of my computer with Macrium Reflect before installing Ubuntu, but I did not create a recovery DVD.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you did, indeed, format your hard drive and install Ubuntu over everything. You're going to have to reinstall Windows, but it's going to be tricky. Use `Gparted` in Ubuntu to make a new `NTFS` partition. Install Windows to this partition. Once that's done, Ubuntu won't be able to boot, so you'll need to use the boot-repair program to fix that. Once you get back into Ubuntu, run `sudo update-grub` and Windows should appear in GRUB.